# How to make a loop stop after it's done iterating through a key's values?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, tuples

Title is a bit complex, and I'm fairly new to Python.

Here's what my problem is,
I currently have a dictionary, and I'm trying to create a tuple according a rule.  I have got the tuple creation under control, I just need a way to iterate differenly so that I can create my tuple

Here's what I have:
The list that "i" goes through is titled `DEMANDPOINT= [1,2,3.......954]`

The second list I have is, a tuple that consists of 734 groups each has 5 numbers, titled `tuples of stations` "j" goes through this

I have a nested dictionary that goes like this: `distance5 = {1: {513: 0.6291397367847646, 279: 0.7823399663201693, 582: 0.8703625254182541, 392: 1.0191414569956174, 297: 1.0660162833624383}, 2: {297: 1.1155101452481397, 279: 1.458507500394341, 513: 1.7296683927743512, 582: 1.8516961940275365, 392: 2.0394772611422898}`

I want "iterator i =1 " to stop after it checks tuple_of_stations's first group of 5 numbers, and switch to 2.

Here's the code that I'm using to create my tuple.

```
for i in DEMANDPOINT:
    for j in tuple_of_stations:
        if distance5[i][j] <= Dc:
            N[i] += (j,)
    if len(N[i]) == 0:    
        N[i] += ((min(distance5[i], key=distance5[i].get)),)
```

I want the "iterator i" to stop after it has checked the values of 1st dictionary. I have no idea how I can do that.

Basically like this: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuhZk.png) In the example, I have explained how I want the iterators to go through.

Sorry if that's not a clear explanation, I tried to explain my problem as much as I could. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry man, I didn't catch if you want to iterate on the first five elements of each element of the dictionary, because in this case it's not the iterator i to be interrupted, but it's j the one you are interested about.

Comment: @Marco Valle I understand, how can I proceed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a little the code, let me know if now it does what you need:

```
N = {}
for i in distance5:
    tuple_of_stations = list(distance5[i].keys())
    c = 0
    for j in tuple_of_stations:
        if distance5[i][j] <= Dc:
            if i not in N:
                N[i] = (j,)
            else:
                N[i] += (j,)
            c += 1
            if c >= 5:
                break
    if i not in N:
        N[i] = ((min(distance5[i], key=distance5[i].get)),)
    elif not N[i]:
        N[i] += ((min(distance5[i], key=distance5[i].get)),)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I got the error 'Key error'

Comment: I need to have more details, because the assignment is not 100% clear for me. Paste in a comment the Key error please.

Comment: The key error I get is like this :KeyError: (513, 279, 582, 392, 297). What else I can  do to explain it further?

Comment: I actually want the iterator to not stop with first five. After checking whether first five values are passing the rule, I want the iterator to pass to 2.

Comment: Now I have implemented a counter, and it stop either after 5 iterations which satisfies the conditions, either when the elements in tuple_of_stations end.

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit. Right now what the code does is creating a tuple but it stops at key 14. I get the error   

KeyError: 14

Comment: Man I'm sorry. I can't understand your task, I'm putting all my efforts, please explain me better what you want to do.

Comment: No problem, I think I'm having a problem explaining it in a clear way. Let me check it on my own, I'll add another comment if I find a way to explain it to you better.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm sorry. Hope to has been a little useful.

Comment: the last edit has worked :) Thanks for the contribution

Comment: Oh nice. I'm happy about that. If you want a vote up would be appreciated. Have a nice day.